# How to fix flex direction to row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a little problem, when a use display flex in the main container for some reason does not work.

The flex direction is always in column. I am already looking for solutions of all kinds and I can't find one that works for me. Maybe it could be a silly mistake and I'm not realizing it, I ask for help with this.

```css
    .box-container a{
        color: var(--goatred-color);
    }
    
    .box-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .box{
        flex: 1 1 300px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .box .image{
        padding: 10px;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: center;    
    }
    
    .box .image img{
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
        object-fit: cover;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.7))
    }
    
    
    .box .title .info{
        padding: 10px;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .box .info .subInfo{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>


            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: What exactly would you like the final result to look like? The text centered in the middle of the page?

Comment: It looks like in your code snippet above the box container class isn't being applied to an html tag.

Comment: @TannerDolby I'm looking for something like a product layout, and even though I remove the flex-wrap: wrap, they still don't get in row

Comment: flex: 1 1 300px; is irrelevant without a flex parent

Comment: @Hyetigran If it has, I only extracted that part that is the one that fails

Comment: @ReyPJ I see, you'll need to apply "display: flex" to your "box" div. However, it would make every child element displayed in a row. To avoid that, wrap each image and info divs in a "card" div.

Comment: @TannerDolby A grid layout, let me a second for search a picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You had one box element, I believe your intention is to have many boxes as elements which behave like rows. I added this HTML fix.
2. I slightly modified the padding of the content to be left aligned, see how the title of each box and the price were not left aligned.

If you agree with the solution then great. If you disagree I kindly ask you to look over the changes and try to modify it to your needs.

Note: expand the snippet to full width, you specified flex boxes 300px wide so you need to see it in a wider screen size.

```css
.box-container a {
    color: var(--goatred-color);
}
    
    .box-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .box{
        flex: 1 1 300px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .box .image{
        padding: 10px;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: center;    
    }
    
    .box .image img{
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
        object-fit: cover;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.7))
    }
    
    
    .box .info{
        padding: 10px;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .box .info .subInfo{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

        <div class="box">
            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/Jer1s.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3 class="titulo">Goat Esports <span>Jersey 2020</span></h3>
                <div class="subInfo">
                    <div class="price">₡14.900</div>
                    <div class="stars">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="" style="--i:1;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:2;" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href="" style="--i:3;" class="fas fa-search"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```